# How can you delay an <a> link from loading until after the element animates out of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I styled some  elements with :active and :hover pseudo-selectors, including a "button press" type animation that also triggers animations that slide the  elements out of the viewport.

I'm trying to make a really smooth UX and want to delay the hyperlinked content from loading until after these animations finish.

How can you accomplish this load delay with HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: Use a listener for the `animationend` event of the current element. In the listener, use `window.location = "URL"` to load the target URL of the link.

Comment: IMHO, this sounds like a bad idea. When someone clicks on a link they expect to go to that page immediately. If you add a delay, they're going to think that the click didn't work.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for thoughts and feedback! The idea is to show that the link click worked by animating the current page's content out, and the next page's content in. The UX is influenced by iOS interaction design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the JavaScript [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function to delay your redirect.

For example, if you have a link as below, call the function on link click:

```
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="onBtnClickHandle()">Click Here</a>
```

Create a JavaScript function and add the delay using the `setTimeout` function:

```
  function onBtnClickHandle(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location="https://www.google.com/"
 }, 3000);
}
```

You can set the timeout value as per your animation timing.

**Demo:**

```js
  function onBtnClickHandle(){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.location="https://www.google.com/"
     }, 3000);
    }
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="onBtnClickHandle()">Click Here</a>
```