# I need to make this button have delay when i click then to go others pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

when i add  its not delay then removes it. and its delay, but what should i do to make this button have href to click and delay then joining other pages  (i'm newbie)

conclude that I need when I click and reload 3 seconds to join other pages I do.
I tried many things but it didn't work. I'm very worried about my problem.

Thanks you all.

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 20px;
    background-color: #4bb34e;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1.33;
}

.button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}

.button:active {
    background: #4CAF50;
}

.button__text {
    font: bold 16px "Quicksand", san-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.button--loading .button__text {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.button--loading::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: button-loading-spinner 1s ease infinite;
}

input,
p {
    font: 17px Calibri;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0turn);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="setTimeout(() => this.classList.toggle('button--loading'), 1500)">
<span class="button__text">Submit</span></button>
```

Comment: So what u need exactly? On click have delay 3sec and start animation, or what?)

Comment: Yes after click then show reload and go up to pages

Comment: Add `location.href = "new href"` to your `onclick=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jquery to fix this, try this method:

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.button').addClass("button--loading");
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';    // replace your URL
    }, 3000);

});
```

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1px 20px;
    background-color: #4bb34e;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1.33;
}

.button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
    content: '\00bb';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
}

.button:active {
    background: #4CAF50;
}

.button__text {
    font: bold 16px "Quicksand", san-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.button--loading .button__text {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.button--loading::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: button-loading-spinner 1s ease infinite;
}

input,
p {
    font: 17px Calibri;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

@keyframes button-loading-spinner {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0turn);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="button">
<span class="button__text">Submit</span></button>
```

Comment: $('.button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.button').addClass("button--loading");
        location.href = 'home.html';
    }, 3000);

});
----
i add home.html to href but click its not happend

Comment: I just tested and this working - https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/v87gops1/1/

Comment: Okay i do again its works my bad thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, which is similar to your question :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69774273/17282751

Use the JavaScript [`setTimeout`][1] function to delay your redirect.

For example, if you have a link as below, call the function on link click:

```
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="onBtnClickHandle()">Click Here</a>
```

Create a JavaScript function and add the delay using the `setTimeout` function:

```
  function onBtnClickHandle(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location="https://www.google.com/"
 }, 3000);
}
```

You can set the timeout value as per your animation timing.

Comment: i tried do this but its not work, idk what did I do wrong

Comment: now its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this

```
  <button type="button" class="button" onclick="waitAndRedirect(this, 'https\://google.com')">
    <span class="button__text">Submit</span>
  </button>
  <script>
    let id
    function waitAndRedirect(elem, url) {
      elem.classList.toggle('button--loading')
      if (id) {
        clearTimeout(id)
        id = null
      } else {
        id = setTimeout(() => {
          window.location.replace(url)
        }, 3000)
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks its works, but i want to go pages home.html that i do how can i edit?

Comment: you just need to replace 'https\://google.com' with 'home.html'

Comment: if your path is localhost:5500/index/index.html use
'/home.html' will redirect you to localhost:5500/home.html